# Why is Morse code used in satellite communication compared to ASCII encoding

Tags: telecommunication

My knowledge about methods of transmission of data is limited, but I believe that communication between transmitters and receivers often uses Morse code to send information.

If say, a satellite wanted to send a message consisting of letters from the English Alphabet, wouldn't it be possible to send it via either Morse, or ASCII, i.e., 'A' may be sent as .- (which may then be translated to the most appropriate form to be transmitted over an EM Wave) or as 01000001?

Is there any reason why Morse is preferred?

Comment: The premise of your question is false. Morse code is *not* used to communicate with satellites.

Comment: Though there may be a very distant similarity. The data is compressed, often using Huffman or similar algorithms: the most frequently repeating fragments are replaced with the compression shortest tokens. Morse Code was a precursor to this compression, assigning the shortest codes to most frequently used letters. ('E' is a `.` T is `-`. A is `.-`. N is `-.`. Rarely used letters get lengthy codes, like Q: `--.-` ) That might have been the source of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Morse isn't used to communicate with satellites. In its simplest form, satellite communications are done by digitizing the text, encoding it into blocks or "packets" (ASCII can be used here), tagging the block or packet with routing information headers and footers, and transmitting the resulting bit string.